# regexp_replace in database to reverse a numeric string and insert a period between each digit

Tags: mysql, regex, postgresql

I have database where one column contains numbers. 3 example values:

```
1111111555
2222222555
3333333555
```

which I need to reverse and put a dot between each digit. i.e. the result for each of the examples above would be:

```
5.5.5.1.1.1.1.1.1.1
5.5.5.2.2.2.2.2.2.2
5.5.5.3.3.3.3.3.3.3
```

respectively.

I then need to update another column with the result. How can I make such replacement?

An online regexp test is giving me the result I need with this:

```
(\S)(\S)(\S)(\S)(\S)(\S)(\S)(\S)(\S)(\S)/g$10.$9.$8.$7.$6.$5.$4.$3.$2.$1
```

but I can't get it to successfully update the database. Any ideas how make it work?

Comment: I've just checked: PostgreSQL only allows a maximum of 9 capturing groups, so you can't use a regex for this, it seems.

Comment: You have tagged your question as both mysql and postgresql. Please indicate which database you are actually using or if you require a solution for both.

Comment: I will use any database which will give me result.
It can be mysql postrgesql or oracle.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have much in the way of regex support at all. And Oracle has the same limitation as PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

Correct answer for PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reverse_array(ANYARRAY) RETURNS ANYARRAY AS $$
    SELECT array( (SELECT $1[i] FROM generate_series( array_upper($1, 1), array_lower($1, 1), -1 ) i ) );
$$ language sql;

# select array_to_string(
    reverse_array(
        regexp_split_to_array( i, '' )
    ), '.'
  )
  from (values ('1111111555'), ('2222222555'), ('3333333555')) x (i);
   array_to_string
---------------------
 5.5.5.1.1.1.1.1.1.1
 5.5.5.2.2.2.2.2.2.2
 5.5.5.3.3.3.3.3.3.3
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. reverse the string by conventional means (i.e., a built-in string function)
2. regex-replace `(\d)` with `$1.`, globally
3. remove the last dot from the result

More complex regexes could save you the last step, for example by means of look-ahead. I'm not sure what your DBMS of choice supports here, so I kept it simple.

Comment: Just in case it is supported: replace `(\d)(?=\d)` with `$1.`

Comment: @Amarghosh: PostgreSQL is the only one that supports lookahead, so that should work. Lookbehind is not supported, though.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, assuming your starting value is in a column called `f` you could do:

```
substr(regexp_replace(reverse(f), '(\d)', '\1.'), 0, (length(f) * 2) - 1)
```

This is using the approach outlined by [Tomalek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak)

Of course you could hard code `19` in place of `(length(f) * 2) - 1` if you know that the original value is always going to be exactly 10 digits.

MySQL has a function for doing regexp matching but doesn't support regexp substitution so you would need to do nested replacement of each digit 0-9 in turn. e.g. for 1-3:

```
replace(replace(replace(reverse(f), '3', '3.'), '2', '2.'), '1', '1.')
```

Comment: Mysql also working for this with you solution, but results are strange if there is more than 10 digits:
1.1..1.1..1.1..1.1..1.1..1. 
2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2. 
Looks like it understands well only untill 9 references, is there any way to use more?

Comment: It seems to work OK for me with longer values e.g. select replace(replace(replace(reverse('11111111111222222222211111111'),
'3', '3.'), '2', '2.'), '1', '1.'); gives "1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1." - What is the value that you're trying it with?

Comment: Yes it's working very nice.
I didn't understood clearly how it's working, and used something like ....(REPLACE(REVERSE(number), '12', '12.'), '11', '11.'),.....
because of 2 digit, I had strange result. But now it's ok.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(reverse(yourcol), E'(\\S)(?=\\S)', E'\\1.', 'g')
```

should work. And to update, of course

```
UPDATE yourtable SET yourcol=regexp_replace(...)
```

Comment: He also wants to reverse it - I missed it as well :(

Comment: Gah. I have reverse() in there for that, forgot that this is a custom function I've put in my local database :S Why don't we have reverse()?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying oracle:
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE(REVERSE(phone),'(\d)','\1.')
from records

4.3.2.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.

This working fine for me, even last dot is useful, I'm going to attach there e164.arpa
with concat. But this is next question.

Thanks alot all of you!!